# Map Reduce Job is reported as complete on history server while on console it shows as only half way thru

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am running a MRV1 job on Hadoop YARN 2.3.0 cluster , the problem is when I submit this job YARN created multiple applications for that submitted job , and the last application that is running in YARN is marked as complete even as on console its reported as only 58% complete . I have confirmed that its also not printing the log statements that its supposed to print when the job is actually complete .

Please see the output from the job submission console below. It just stops at 58% and job history server and YARN cluster UI reports that this job has already succeeded.

```
4/08/28 08:36:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 54% reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:44:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 55% reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:52:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 56% reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:59:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 57% reduce 0%
14/08/28 09:07:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 58% reduce 0%
```

Thanks.